# How to check if an Ant task is available in the current JVM?

Tags: java, ant

All our projects' `build.xml` files, designed to be run in Eclipse, contain invocations to the special `<eclipse.refreshLocal depth="infinite" resource="/" />` defined only in Eclipse.

We must configure Ant to use the same JVM as the workspace in order for it to be run, otherwise we get an error.

In order to *export* the same build scripts to platforms such as Bamboo and Travis, how do I modify the invocation in order to be conditional? I mean, if the task is not found, just ignore it. If I run my Ant scripts in Bamboo I expect an error for sure!